# Заменить нижнюю часть матрицы на нули

Tags: python

Есть задача заменить верхнюю половину матрицы NxN на единицы кроме тех, которые слева от главной диагонали. Я думал так: заменить всё что выше главной диагонали на единицы и потом просто заменить всё что в нижней половине матрицы на 0. Заменил всё что выше главной диагонали на 1, но вот никак не пойму как заменить нижнюю половину матрицы на 0.
пробовал делать так:

```
n#размер строк и столбиков 
half=n/2
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i and j>half:
            matrix[i][j] = 0
```

но вышло это :

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

а хотелось:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Там уже нижняя половина

Comment: А если строк нечетное количество, то верхняя половина с какой строки начинается?

Comment: ну скорее всего можно округлить до первого знака (типа если 5, то половина 2,5 и оставить только 2). Думаю через round это будет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось как-то так:

```py
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]]

n = len(matrix)

half = n // 2

if n % 2 == 1:
    n -= 1
for i in range(half):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i:
            matrix[i][j] = 1

print(matrix)
```

Должно работать и с четным, и с нечетным количеством строк/столбцов

Comment: Ля, это рили гениально не лезть в ту нижнюю половину. Огромное спасибо!